# Specflow Editor not working in Feature file after the latest

Tags: specflow

We are using Visual Studio 2017 and using Specflow as unit testing tool.
We have added "Specflow for Visual Studio 2017" as extension so that we have the editor in feature file.

Everything was working fine as expected and we were able to edit feature file. However after there was some upgrade from Specflow side, the editor is now not working

Any inputs ?

Comment: What is the error? What is not working?

Comment: The issue was that the Specflow Feature file was not editable. We then updated Visual Studio and it again was now editable. So the issue is now resolved